# FTP or Cpanel installation of WordPress

Tags: ftp

I have done both FTP and cPanel installations of WordPress but which is the better way to go in terms of installation? Taking into account that the client wants to be the one to have control over everything in the long run. i have been reading and I see that issues may arise in terms of the hosting company deploying updates when WordPress was installed through FTP. Many cases also recommending installation by way of cPanel as to have a smoother process in the long run. So which is the way to go? cPanel or FTP?

Comment: They're essentially the same. The benefit to a CPanel installation is that the host typically monitors what version of WordPress is in use and if there's a security update many hosts will automatically handle that update for the client. So if they're likely to be hands-off and need someone else to keep the site updated for them, CPanel may help a bit (assuming you're not offering a maintenance package, in which case you might prefer FTP so you're the one notifying them of updates, not the host).

Comment: Yes am not offering a maintenance package so am guessing cPanel would be the better choice, right?

Comment: Yep, I'd lean that way, to try to help them keep their site up to date.

Answer (score 1):

Unless the hosting provider adds in some custom plugins, there should be no difference in the actual installation of Wordpress when using a cPanel 1-click option or uploading directly via FTP.

Once the site is installed, there is not really any more interaction with cPanel, other than being able to easily delete the database and files associated with the install.

If your client wishes to be the only person with access/ control of the site after build then ensure that only they have an administrator account in Wordpress and only they have the details to login to the hosting, cPanel, FTP, etc.